# WHERE clause, probably simple but i cant see it

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a SQL where clause question that I hope you can help me with. I am trying to filter the results of my product database query to not retrieve specified products types where the stock received date is greater than the 01/10/19, if the products types are in the database with another date that is less than 01/10/19 then it should also be included in the results.

In the example below I don't want the SQL to display any products with the product type "446" that has a product received date that is >= 01/10/2019. So the milk product with the batch number "AE0152" I don't want to be included in the results but the milk product with the batch number "AE0142" I do.

I hope this makes sense. I have tried to a few different combinations but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
Product No:     Product Description:    Product Type:   Product received date:  Batch Number:
00001441        Milk                    446              30/09/2019             AE0142
00001441        Eggs                    446              15/10/2019             AE0151
00001441        Milk                    446              04/10/2019             AE0152
00001441        Flour                   450              08/10/2019             AE0201
00001441        Sugar                   450              08/10/2019             AE0201
00001441        800g White loaf         500              14/10/2019             AE0232
```

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using: oracle, mysql, sql-server...? Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: Also, please show us the result that you would expect for this sample data.

Comment: A simple `WHERE ProductReceivedDate < '20191001'` should do it but I believe you're storing dates as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE ProductId <> 446 -- Get all products that are not "446"
OR (ProductId = 446 AND rec_date < DATE '2019-10-01') -- Get certain "446" products
```

**Updated**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE (
  prod_type <> 446 OR -- get all non-446 products
  rec_date < DATE '2019-10-01' -- Get all products that meet date restriction
)
```

This will block rows where `prod_type = 446 AND date >= '2019-10-01'` is true, which I think is what you're asking for.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that will only exclude the product type 446 or include the product type 446 that has a date of < 01/10/2019. I need to to retrieve all products except product types 446 that have a date greater than 01/10/2019.

Comment: Ah ok, I must have misread it.  I think in that case you can change the `WHERE` clause to be `type <> 446 OR rec_date < DATE '2019-10-01'`.  See updated answer.

Comment: no that still won't as it excludes all products with the product type '446' or records with a date less than 2019/10/01.  I need to see all dates. I only don't want to see products with the type '446' code that are after 2019-10-01 I want to be able to see everything else.

Comment: Take a look at this DB Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/28878c/2.  It excludes only product 446 after the date you specified.  It allows product 446 with an earlier date to go through (i.e. "Milk AE0142").  Is that not what you want?  In the fiddle, which product_codes (i.e. AE0142) do you expect to be returned and which ones do you expect not to?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select * from table_name where product_received_date < '2019-10-01'
```

**UPDATED**

```
select * from table_name where product_received_date < '2019-10-01' || product_type = 446
```

Change the date format according to database like Y-m-d or d-m-Y.
If your `product_received_date` is of type `string` then specify the date in same format in where clause.

Comment: Hi Anshu, no unfortunately that would only bring back products with of a date less than 2019-10-01 I need to see all dates. I only don't want to see products with the type '446' code that are after 2019-10-01 I want to be able to see everything else.

Comment: @Andypm Have you checked by applying one more condition for product type '446' like `select * from table_name where product_received_date < '2019-10-01' and product_type != 446`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE (ProductId <> 446 AND rec_date >  DATE '2019-10-01')`

Comment: Hi! Unfortuently not. That will only bring back products types that are not '446' with a product date of more than 2019-10-01. I only don't want to see products with the type '446' code that are after 2019-10-01 however  I want to be able to see everything else in the same report.